Environment Variables in Docker Compose Not Overriding appsettings.json in .NET Core Application
I'm running a .NET Core web application inside Docker using Docker Compose, but I'm having trouble getting the environment variables specified in my docker-compose.yml file to override the connection strings defined in appsettings.json.
Despite setting the ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection environment variable in docker-compose.yml, the application still uses the connection string from appsettings.json or appsettings.Development.json, which points to localhost. This causes a connection error when the application tries to connect to the PostgreSQL database running in another Docker container.

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Copy the solution file
COPY test-docker.sln ./
COPY test-docker/test-docker.csproj test-docker/

RUN dotnet restore test-docker.sln

COPY . .

# Build and publish the application
WORKDIR /app/test-docker
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/out

# Stage 2: Runtime Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test-docker.dll"]


docker-compose.yml:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  webapp:
    image: test-docker-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: test-docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Host=db;Port=5432;Database=mydatabase;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

volumes:
  pgdata:

appsettings.Development.json:
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=mydatabase;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword"
  }
}

The problem:
when run the app on docker
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5432


Why not introduce a second appSettings.Docker entirely?

@SanchoPanza
still experiencing the same issue despite trying your suggested solution

You probably need to have ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection env var to be named smth like AppSettings__ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection. See the question

You can verify if Docker is setting the right variables by printing them. You can use the below command and confirm:
docker exec -it <container_id> printenv | grep ConnectionStrings
